# Weird custom info window rendering with angular-google-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

> Available plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/v5is6kXdT5ezQdb9OeGr?p=preview)

Using the `angular-google-maps` directive I'm trying to display several markers and only one custom window at a time on a map.

The `custom info` window content is placed in a external template (infoWindow.tpl.html), set as `templateUrl` in the `ui-gmap-window` directive:

```
  <ui-gmap-window 
    show="map.window.show" 
    coords="map.window.model" 
    options="map.window.options" 
    closeClick="map.window.closeClick()"
    templateUrl="'infowindow.tpl.html'">
```

Everything is working fine, and when the marker is clicked, the info window is displayed. However, the window rendering has a weird effect (it can be easily seen in the plunker). It looks like it's not waiting for all the content to be loaded before rendering the window.

I tried setting `ng-cloak` to the container div of `infowindow.tpl.html`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
<div ng-cloak>
  <p>Some content</p>
  <img ng-src="https://material.angularjs.org/latest/img/washedout.png" class="md-card-image" alt="Washed Out">
</div>
```

I also tried with `ng-cloak` directly on the `ui-gmap-window`, but it doesn't change anything either.

```
<ui-gmap-window 
...
ng-cloak>
```

Any ideas of how this weird effect can be avoided?

Thanks